# MIPS Fibonacci Using Recursion

Tags: recursion, mips, fibonacci

So, I am working on fibonacci in MIPS, and the rules are I need to have a preamble for a recursive method of solving the problem. My code currently is producing wrong output and I cannot identify which part should be edited.

```
.text

main:   li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $a0, $v0
    move $v0, $zero
    jal fibo

    move $t2, $v0
    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t2
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall


fibo:   ####preamble####    #push from stack
        subu $sp, $sp, 32
        sw $ra, 0($sp)      #store return address
        sw $a0, 4($sp)
        sw $fp, 8($sp)
        sw $v0, 12($sp)
        addu $fp, $sp, 32
        ####preamble####    

zero:   bne $a0, 0, one
        move $v0, $a0
        jr $ra  

one:    bne $a0, 1, fn1
        move $v0, $a0
        jr $ra  

fn1:    subi $a0, $a0, 1    #call for fibo(n-1)
        jal fibo            #recursive

        lw $a0, 4($sp)
        addi $a0, $a0, 1

        subi $a0, $a0, 2    #call for fibo(n-2) 
        jal fibo        

result: lw $ra, 0($sp)      #load ra
        lw $fp, 8($sp)
        lw $t0, 12($sp)
        add $v0, $t0, $v0
        addu $sp, $sp, 32
        addu $fp, $fp, 32   
        jr $ra
```

Comment: SPIM/MARS has a single-step feature that you can use to step through your code instruction-by-instruction.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, provide the actual output, the expected output, and the results of your attempts to trace it so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you had the basic structure and components correct, but, unfortunately, there were a number of bugs.

I've created two versions of your program. One with comments detailing the bugs. And, a second version with things cleaned up, simplified, and working

---

Here's the annotated version [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
    .text

main:
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    move    $a0,$v0

    # NOTE/BUG: doing this is unnecessary/wrong if fibo is correct
    move    $v0,$zero

    jal     fibo

    move    $t2,$v0
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$t2
    syscall

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

####preamble####    #push from stack
fibo:
    # NOTE/BUG: for simple functions like this, setting up fp is extra work
    # NOTE/BUG: we want to have extra space in the frame but we don't need
    # to push/pop for some
    subu    $sp,$sp,32
    sw      $ra,0($sp)              # store return address
    sw      $a0,4($sp)
    sw      $fp,8($sp)
    sw      $v0,12($sp)
    addu    $fp,$sp,32
    ####preamble####

    # NOTE/BUG: we must zero out t0 so that the add in result: is valid

    # NOTE/BUG: a stack frame has already been established -- it must be popped
    # we can _not_ just do a "jr" here
zero:
    bne     $a0,0,one
    move    $v0,$a0
    jr      $ra

    # NOTE/BUG: a stack frame has already been established -- it must be popped
one:
    bne     $a0,1,fn1
    move    $v0,$a0
    jr      $ra

fn1:
    subi    $a0,$a0,1               # call for fibo(n-1)
    jal     fibo                    # recursive

    # NOTE/BUG: we must save the result for fibo(n-1) in our stack frame

    # NOTE/BUG: this is incorrect -- by doing it, we [effectively] do fibo(n-1)
    # again (i.e.) (n+1)-2 --> (n-1) and _not_ (n-2) as we wish
    # do one of these but _not_ both
    lw      $a0,4($sp)
    addi    $a0,$a0,1

    subi    $a0,$a0,2               # call for fibo(n-2)
    jal     fibo

    # NOTE/BUG: fibo(n-1) must be added to fibo(n-2)

result:
    lw      $ra,0($sp)              # load ra
    lw      $fp,8($sp)

    # NOTE/BUG: this is misplaced because entering this block should already
    # have v0 set correctly
    lw      $t0,12($sp)
    add     $v0,$t0,$v0

    # NOTE/BUG: the correct way to restore $fp is using: lw $fp,8($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,32
    addu    $fp,$fp,32
    jr      $ra
```

---

Here's the working version:

```
    .data
msg_ask:    .asciiz     "Enter n for fibonacci(n) (-1=stop): "
msg_fibo:   .asciiz     "fibonacci(n) is: "
msg_nl:     .asciiz     "\n"
    .text

main:
    # prompt user
    la      $a0,msg_ask
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # get number from user
    li      $v0,5
    syscall
    move    $a0,$v0
    bltz    $a0,main_exit

    jal     fibo
    move    $t2,$v0                 # save the result

    # print message
    la      $a0,msg_fibo
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    # print the result
    li      $v0,1
    move    $a0,$t2
    syscall

    # print message
    la      $a0,msg_nl
    li      $v0,4
    syscall

    j       main

main_exit:
    li      $v0,10
    syscall

# fibo -- recursive fibonacci
#
# RETURNS:
#   v0 -- fibonacci(n)
#
# arguments:
#   a0 -- the "n" for the Nth fibonacci number
#
# registers:
#   t0 -- temporary
fibo:
    # fibo(0) is 0 and fibo(1) is 1 -- no need to establish a stack frame
    bgt     $a0,1,fibo_full         # do we need recursion? if yes, fly
    move    $v0,$a0                 # no, just set return value
    jr      $ra                     # fast return

    # establish stack frame
    # we need an extra cell (to preserve the result of fibo(n-1))
fibo_full:
    # this gives us a temp word at 0($sp)
    subu    $sp,$sp,12              # one more than we need
    sw      $ra,4($sp)
    sw      $a0,8($sp)

    subi    $a0,$a0,1               # call for fibo(n-1)
    jal     fibo                    # recursive
    sw      $v0,0($sp)              # save result in our frame (in extra cell)

    subi    $a0,$a0,1               # call for fibo(n-2)
    jal     fibo                    # recursive

    lw      $t0,0($sp)              # restore fibo(n-1) from our stack frame
    add     $v0,$t0,$v0             # result is: fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2)

    # restore from stack frame
    lw      $ra,4($sp)
    lw      $a0,8($sp)
    addu    $sp,$sp,12

    jr      $ra                     # return
```